# Book about a transport spaceship

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, space

I read this book end somewhere between 1999-2006.

I think it was part of a series. I believe I read 2 or 3. I believe it was labelled as a young adult book. I think it had some sex in it but my memory is hazy.

It's about a female who pilots a Cargo/Transport spaceship. (I believe her name started with a K or possibly the authors name started with a K.)

She transports cargo to different planets or ships to make money. (The currency might have been referred to as Credits, not sure though)

I think there was some sort of body modification in it. (For example, someone could modify themselves to feel more pleasure or feel no pain. I can't remember but they may also have been able to have chips installed for telecommunication. There may also have been people with android parts but I'm hazy on that part.)

I believe the cover had the main character on it with a ship in the background but I can't remember.

Every few years it pops into my head but it's so vague that I can't seem to find it when I search Google.

I think you can classify it as an Action-Adventure with some undertones of Romance.

Comment: I saw a book in Dymocks just yesterday that matches your description of the cover, with a female and ship in the background in empty space with a planet and all. I will bookmark this question and then later in the day come back to tell you what the book is if you still don't have an answer. I think the author might have even had a name starting with K. *Edit*: Doing some research, do you perhaps wish to find a 1998 book called **Komarr** by Lois McMaster Bujold?

Comment: @user477343  Or it could be Shards of Honor, which is earlier in the same series by Lois McMaster Bujold. https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1416728.Shards_of_Honor    They have implant chips there for pilots.

Comment: I believe I just remembered the book I saw at Dymocks. I think it was called **The Stars are Legion** written by Kameron Hurley. Going over here, https://www.amazon.com/Stars-Are-Legion-Kameron-Hurley/dp/1481447939 I found that the book has a female character named *Zan*, but given the other details, I don't think this is the book you are looking for. It was also published in February 2017, so it could not have been. But going to the link, maybe it might remind you more about the book you are looking for?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Yes, however from your link, it is mentioned that none of Lois' books contain explicit sexual content. Perhaps the book never had any sex in it after all.

Comment: Turns out the book that I apparently remembered, wasn't the book at all (but it was close). Going to Dymocks, the book that I saw was **Scales of Empire** by Kylie Chan. The book is Book 1 of the **Dragon Empire Trilogy** but was published on the 19 February this year, so it definitely was *not* the book you were looking for, although it did have a female character named *Corporal Jian Choumaliis*.

Comment: @user477343 The OP was hazy about the sex, so not a deal breaker ;-)

Comment: @Dijkgraaf yeah, true that :)

Comment: Maybe Elizabeth Moon's Vatta's War Series (5 books) First book "Trading in Danger" came out in 2003. Main Character is named Kylara. Kylara a favored daughter of a wealthy, interstellar shipping family, gets thrown ignominiously out of the Space Academy. In consolation, her father gives her an antiquated cargo ship, the Glennys Jones, to command. He assumes she'll find a way to make enough profit to keep from having to junk the old tub. People also use Implants in the head to access/store data and control equipment and access computers comms and news.

Comment: I'm not sure how to mark this as complete but thank you NJohnny. It is the Vatta's War Series by Elizabeth Moon. (I think the sex part might be from a different series that my brain merged with this one)

Comment: Does the pilot hey health issues from piloting, weaker bones etc..?  Due to damage from navigating grimspace.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I think I am also looking for the same book. And I think the series had Legion in the title, but it's definitely not the one stated above.

Answer (score 3):

[@NJohnny](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/182260/book-about-a-transport-spaceship#comment494393_182260) was on point:

> Maybe Elizabeth Moon's Vatta's War Series (5 books) First book "Trading in Danger" came out in 2003. Main Character is named Kylara. Kylara a favored daughter of a wealthy, interstellar shipping family, gets thrown ignominiously out of the Space Academy. In consolation, her father gives her an antiquated cargo ship, the Glennys Jones, to command. He assumes she'll find a way to make enough profit to keep from having to junk the old tub. People also use Implants in the head to access/store data and control equipment and access computers comms and news.

It's Elizabeth Moon's [Vatta's War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatta%27s_War) Series (5 books).